# Unwanted black lines

Tags: rendering, materials, light, lighting

Can you help me by explaining how to get rid of those black lines in Blender? Thank you very much.

[image]

Comment: Could you show us some screenshots of your material setup and maybe share your blend file via https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com? It's hard to tell exactly what's going on from one single render.

Comment: That's either due to too few transmission (transparent) passes or lacking geometry. My guess is the former, increase the bounces for the two in the render settings.